# Rails : Moving a column from a table to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner and I can't move a table column(doctors.specialty) to another table column(specialties.name).

This is the doctors table:

tp Doctor.all

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SPECIALTY | ZIP_CODE | CREATED_AT | UPDATED_AT | CITY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cathy | Wyman | Gynecologist | 78328 | 2022-07-28 13:48:57 | 2022-07-28 14:33:51 | 17 |
| 2 | Dave | Howell | General practitioner | 97544 | 2022-07-28 13:48:57 | 2022-07-28 14:33:51 | 13 |
| 3 | Zachariah | Stamm | Anesthesiology | 08435-1702 | 2022-07-28 13:48:57 | 2022-07-28 14:33:51 | 4 |
| 4 | Forrest | Koelpin | General practitioner | 58486 | 2022-07-28 13:48:57 | 2022-07-28 14:33:51 | 16 |
| 5 | Cameron | Zieme | Anesthesiology | 01200 | 2022-07-28 13:48:57 | 2022-07-28 14:33:51 | 13 |
| 6 | Chia | Borer | Gynecologist | 81913-8875 | 2022-07-28 13:48:57 | 2022-07-28 14:25:11 | 18 |
| 7 | Sonny | Torphy | Gynecologist | 08593-7841 | 2022-07-28 13:48:57 | 2022-07-28 14:33:51 | 4 |

I generated a new model:
`rails g model Specialty name:string doctor_id:integer`

I generated a new migration
rails g migration MoveColumnDataToSpecialty

I tried this code but it didn't work and i'm not sure that I should use it to move the column

```
class MoveColumnDataToSpecialty < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :some_property, :string
    execute "UPDATE users u SET some_property = p.some_property FROM profiles p WHERE u.id = p.user_id;"
    remove_column :profiles, :some_property
  end

  def self.down
    add_column :profiles, :some_property, :string
    execute "UPDATE profiles p SET some_property = u.some_property FROM users u WHERE p.user_id = u.id;"
    remove_column :users, :some_property
  end
end
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `rails g model Specialty name:string doctor_id:integer` -- don't sure it's good idea. Column `doctors.speciality_id` looks better than `specialities.doctor_id`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create `specialties` table, then add column with FK to `doctors` table. After that insert into `specialties` existed names and make associations between tables. Finally you can remove unused column

Rollback migration -- reverse order

```
def self.up
  create_table :specialties do |t|
    t.string :name
  end

  change_table :doctors do |t|
    t.belongs_to :specialty, foreign_key: true
  end

  specialties = Doctor.pluck(:specialty).uniq

  specialties_ids_names =
    Specialty.insert_all!(
      specialties.map { |specialty| { name: specialty } },
      returning: %w[id name]
    )

  specialties_ids_names.rows.each do |specialty_id, name|
    # Here raw SQL column to prevent disambiguates with association
    Doctor.where('doctors.specialty = ?', name).update_all(specialty_id: specialty_id)
  end

  remove_column :doctors, :specialty
end
```

```
def self.down
  add_column :doctors, :specialty, :string

  Specialty.pluck(:id, :name).each do |specialty_id, name|
    # Here raw SQL column to prevent disambiguates with association
    Doctor.where(specialty_id: specialty_id).update_all("specialty = #{name}")
  end

  remove_column :doctors, :specialty_id

  drop_table :specialties
end
```

Note: `insert_all` was introduced in Rails 6. Instead of this method, you can create records one by one or use raw SQL `INSERT INTO specialties VALUES` using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.insert_sql`